# Applying pseudo-class for a checkbox to a specific sibling

Tags: css, tailwind-css, pseudo-class

I am looking at realizing a CSS Native multilevel menu for a sidebar without using Javascript (or the `setState` in my current React implementation).
I have done almost everything, but I am getting stuck with an additional feature, i.e. rotating the chevron 90 degrees when the checkbox is checked.

Each group opens to a level which can contain an additional level. I am trying to not use named groups/peers so that I can easily generate this from e.g. a JSON file.

I tried to change the `peer` position and using `group` without any luck. I could possibly refactor my code, to swap elements and achieve it, but that would probably not be the correct solution.

I have this code available. All works, but the chevron does not rotate.

```html
<div class="container mx-auto flex h-screen">
  <div class="flex w-48 flex-col bg-slate-100">
    <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 1</div>
    <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 2</div>
    <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 3</div>
    <label class="cursor-pointer">
      <input type="checkbox" class="peer hidden cursor-pointer select-none rounded-lg bg-slate-500 ease-in-out">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
        <span>Group 1</span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="h-4 w-4 peer-checked:rotate-90">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="m8.25 4.5 7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5" /></svg
      ></div></input>

      <div class="relative hidden pl-4 peer-checked:block">
        <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 1-1</div>
        <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 1-2</div>
        <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 1-3</div>
        <label class="peer cursor-pointer">
          <input type="checkbox" class="peer hidden cursor-pointer select-none rounded-lg bg-slate-500 ease-in-out" />
          <span class="flex items-center justify-between">
            <span>Group 2</span>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="h-4 w-4">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="m8.25 4.5 7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5" /></svg
          ></span>
          <div class="relative hidden pl-4 peer-checked:block">
            <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 2-1</div>
            <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 2-2</div>
            <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 2-3</div>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-1 bg-lime-100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

Peers of the `<svg>` would only be the `<span>` as `peer-` uses the sibling CSS combinator, `+`. To rotate the `<svg>` depending on the `<input>` you could consider using a `group`, with an arbitrary modifier,

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.0"></script>

<div class="container mx-auto flex h-screen">
  <div class="flex w-48 flex-col bg-slate-100">
    <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 1</div>
    <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 2</div>
    <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 3</div>
    <label class="cursor-pointer">
      <input type="checkbox" class="peer hidden cursor-pointer select-none rounded-lg bg-slate-500 ease-in-out">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between group">
        <span>Group 1</span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="h-4 w-4 group-[:checked+&]:rotate-90">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="m8.25 4.5 7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5" /></svg
      ></div>

      <div class="relative hidden pl-4 peer-checked:block">
        <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 1-1</div>
        <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 1-2</div>
        <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 1-3</div>
        <label class="peer cursor-pointer">
          <input type="checkbox" class="peer hidden cursor-pointer select-none rounded-lg bg-slate-500 ease-in-out" />
          <span class="flex items-center justify-between group">
            <span>Group 2</span>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="h-4 w-4 group-[:checked+&]:rotate-90">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="m8.25 4.5 7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5" /></svg
          ></span>
          <div class="relative hidden pl-4 peer-checked:block">
            <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 2-1</div>
            <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 2-2</div>
            <div class="hover:bg-pink-300">Item 2-3</div>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-1 bg-lime-100"></div>
</div>
```